# get list of files from path on the internet

Tags: ms-access, vba

[image]

i'm automating a project where every month i need to go on a website and copy a file from there.
i'm able to copy the file, the problem is that they're named like below so there's no way for me to know which file to copy that month.

filename2015011023549.zip

filename2015021922876.zip

is there a way to get a list of files from a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You download the page (see in-line comments) with the file listing to a local file, then parse that file for possible file name candidates:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) _
    As Long

Public Function DownloadFile( _
    ByVal strURL As String, _
    ByVal strLocalFilename As String) _
    As Long

' Download file or page with public access from the web.
' 2004-12-17. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

' Usage, download a file:
' lngRet = DownloadFile("http://www.databaseadvisors.com/Graphics/conf2002/2002ConferencePicsbySmolin/images/dba02smolin27.jpg", "c:\happybassett.jpg")
'
' Usage, download a page:
' lngRet = DownloadFile("http://www.databaseadvisors.com/conf2002/conf200202.asp", "c:\dbaconference.htm")

' Returns 0 if success, error code if not.
' Error codes:
' -2146697210 "file not found".
' -2146697211 "domain not found".

' Limitation.
' Does not check if local file was created successfully.

    Dim lngRetVal As Long

    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL & vbNullChar, strLocalFilename & vbNullChar, 0, 0)

    DownloadFile = lngRetVal

End Function
```